# Insert word at beginning of row - python

Tags: python

I want to insert a word at the beginning of a string for each row in a column where the first word is not *x*. If it is *x*, then move on. For below, *x* = `BP`. So if first word in cat is not `BP`, then insert it.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
   'cat': ['BP STATION', 'STATION', 'BP OLD', 'OLD OLD'],    
   })

df['cat'] = df['cat'].str.replace(r'^\w+', 'BP')
```

intent:

```
             cat
0     BP STATION
1     BP STATION
2         BP OLD
3     BP OLD OLD
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need your search regex to be "not BP" and you need to capture it so that it doesn't get removed in the replacement.  So you want`r'^([^B][^P])`.  And the replacement regex is then `r'BP \1'`.

```
>>> df['cat'] = df['cat'].str.replace(r'^([^B][^P])', r'BP \1')
<stdin>:1: FutureWarning: The default value of regex will change from True to False in a future version.
>>> df
          cat
0  BP STATION
1  BP STATION
2      BP OLD
3  BP OLD OLD
>>>
```

Comment: Just for reference "not BP" is more concisely expressed as `(?!BP)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom function with `apply`:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'cat': ['BP STATION', 'STATION', 'BP OLD', 'OLD OLD'],
})

def insert_word(row):
    if not row.startswith('BP '):
        row = 'BP ' + row
    return row

# Apply the function
df['cat'] = df['cat'].apply(insert_word)
```